# What does an executable look like?

Tags: assembly, binary, hex, executable

if I opened an executable in a HEX Editor would I see 1's and 0's in hexadecimal notation?

Also is it theoretically possible to write an executable by hand, for something simple like a "Hello World" program?

Comment: theres nothing simple about a hello world program.  There is no magic to the files, basically any file a program can write you can write too, by hand, if patient enough.  Bits is bits...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On question one: yes, you would see a bunch of hex digits. But the same is true of any file format. If you open a *text* file in a hex editor, you'd still see a bunch of hex digits. However, if you open a text file in a text editor (e. g. Notepad), you'd see a text, and if you open an executable in a text editor, you'd see nonsense, maybe with some legible text fragments in it.

Yes, it's theoretically possible to create an executable file by hand in a hex editor. With some executable formats it's easier, with some - much harder. The very old [COM format of MS-DOS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COM_file) is the simplest - it has no header whatsoever, the executable code starts at the beginning of the file. The smallest valid COM file is just a few bytes long (maybe even one, I forgot). Modern executable formats - [PE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Executable), [ELF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) - have a fairly large header that describes the rest of the file,  specifying the target machine/OS, where's code, where's data, what functions does it import from dynamic libraries, etc. While creating a file by hand, you'd have to fill out all those header fields, following a spec.

In general, this is not a fruitful endeavor - a compiler/linker combo will create an executable for you with much less effort.

Comment: I think the question wasn't eyeballing bypassing the compiler/linker process, but more trying to get an understanding of if executable files are just "regular" files or if there's OS magic involved.  That's my guess.

Comment: There's no magic to the format itself :) The execute permission on *nix is the closest thing to OS magic there is.

Comment: https://www.muppetlabs.com/~breadbox/software/tiny/teensy.html makes a tiny ELF executable "by hand", using NASM source code for flat binary output to define every byte of the output file.  Fun fact: 3 of the first 4 bytes of an ELF file are actually ASCII text: the 4-byte "magic number" for the file format is `"\x7fELF"`

Answer (score 3):

If you try to see an executable file in text representation, in any text editor, you will see something like:

`^?ELF^B^A^A^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^B^@>^@^A^@^@^@@^D@^@^@^@^@^@@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@x^Q^@^@
^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@@^@8^@  ^@@^@^^^@ES`

This is because there bytes, codes which are not text symbols according to ASCII.

But if you open it in a HEX editor, it will be like:

```
00005f0: 0100 0200 4865 6c6c 6f20 576f 726c 6400  ....Hello World.
0000600: 011b 033b 3400 0000 0500 0000 00fe ffff  ...;4...........
0000610: 8000 0000 40fe ffff 5000 0000 2cff ffff  ....@...P...,...
0000620: a800 0000 50ff ffff c800 0000 e0ff ffff  ....P...........
0000630: f000 0000 0000 0000 1400 0000 0000 0000  ................
```

Here bytes are represented in HEX.

If you need to modify an executable directly, you will most likely find HEX editing as a better way.

Then you can open it in the HEX editor:

[image]

Change a bit:

[image]

and here is a result:

```
ruslan@ruslan-Latitude-E6430:~/Documents$ ./hello 
Hello+World
```